# ElasticSearch Counts filtered by date and user id

Tags: elasticsearch

I am building a proof of concept using `ElasticSearch`, `Logstash` and `Kibana` for a project.

For this project I am ingesting logs from my bespoke application into the `ELK` stack via a `FileBeats` agent.

Within the each log-line is nested JSON which I have successfully extracted into `Kibana` as separate fields `(rawjson.id, rawjson.type, rawjson.datecreated)`.

The challenge I have now is that I am trying to build an `ElasticSearch` query that will return a count summary of these values broken down by `rawjson.datecreated` and then by `rawjson.id` with a count next to each id where `rawjson.type = 'code'`.

I am looking for it to return something like:

```
{
    "results": {
        "usage_by_date": {
            "buckets": [{
                "2015-01-01": [{
                        "rawjson.id": "xxxxx-yyyyy-zzzzz",
                        "count": 23
                    },
                    {
                        "rawjson.id": "yyyyy-zzzzz-xxxxx",
                        "count": 45
                    }
                ],
                "2015-02-01": [{
                        "rawjson.id": "xxxxx-yyyyy-zzzzz",
                        "count": 23
                    },
                    {
                        "rawjson.id": "yyyyy-zzzzz-xxxxx",
                        "count": 45
                    }
                ]
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

What would be the best way to construct this ElasticSearch query to get the rsults back in this format?

Thanks in advance